# Convert XPath selector to jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xpath, automated-tests

For the given (incomplete) HTML table:

```
<tr>
    ...
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio"></td>
    <td>Red Hot Chili Peppers</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio"></td>
    <td>Britney Spears</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    ...
</tr>
```

I use xpath selector `//td[contains(., 'Red Hot Chili Peppers')]//preceding-sibling::td//input` to click a radio button.

The problem is that xpath is sometimes flaky on the page I'm testing. I wish to switch to jQuery.

How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: do you want to click radio button if user click on td containing label i.e. Red Hot Chili Peppers or Britney Spears etc?

Comment: No, I want to click a radio button next to a specific text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery equivalent of that would use `:contains`, `prev()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$('td:contains("Red Hot Chili Peppers")').prev('td').find('input')
```

```js
$('td:contains("Red Hot Chili Peppers")').prev('td').find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio"></td>
    <td>Red Hot Chili Peppers</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio"></td>
    <td>Britney Spears</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what if there are more <td>'s between the input and the <td> with RHCP text?

Comment: The you could use `closest('tr')` then `find()` the `input`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that
check this https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

for your code use

```
$('td:contains("Red Hot Chili Peppers")').prev('td').find('input');
```

I'ld suggest to use jQuery because I has many libraries build on top of it. You will easily find what you need.

Comment: And how can I get the previous element not immediately next to the <td> with wanted text?

Comment: .prev([selector]) fucntion provides the element which matches in immediately preceding siblings.
see doc https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 1):

[`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) is supposed to match ***all*** preceding siblings, the most appropriate jQuery equivalent is [`prevAll`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/):

```
$("td:contains('Red Hot Chili Peppers')")
  .prevAll("td")
  .find("input")
```